# How to make a histogram showing the frequency of word length?

Tags: string-manipulation, histograms

I have to analyze the novel ***Don Quixote***, so I am trying to make a histogram where each bin is how many characters in a word, and the height being the frequency of words with that many characters.

Comment: There's an example of this in the documentation for `WordCounts` (under Applications).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Histogram[
 StringLength[
  ReadList[
    StringToStream[
      ExampleData[{"Text", "DonQuixoteIEnglish"}]], Word]], 20,
  ChartLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]